# In Paper.js, is there a simple way to select the closest point (relative to mouse)?

Tags: paperjs

I wish to interactively move handles or points in a path with the mouse. 
I think I can manage to program a scan in all points and handles and compute the one at mouse position. But is there a more simple way to select them?

Comment: Loop over every point, calculate distance for each point, get the smallest one. No there isn't another simpler way unless paperjs has something builtin. what you could do is divide screen into pieces and check for points for only that piece but that only increases efficiency not reduce complexity.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getNearestPoint(cursorPoint)` method which can be invoked from `Path` item

Link to the documentation with an example:
http://paperjs.org/reference/path/#getnearestpoint-point