# PaperJS how to find the nearest item to a mouse event within a Group item

Tags: javascript, svg, paperjs

I am currently trying to make an interactive editor for a complex & large SVG item with PaperJS. All the paths of the SVG are nested inside of a `Group` object, in fact children of the `Group` object are `CompoundPaths`.

I want to be able to select a specific `Path` within the `Group` via mouse click, but I don't want my script to be (even more) computationally heavy, so I don't want to have to iterate all of the path items (just less than 1000 Path items, yes I know) or to have to try and add event handlers to all path items within the Group.

I have seen another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31227091/in-paper-js-is-there-a-simple-way-to-select-the-closest-point-relative-to-mous) which talks about selecting the nearest point but this method is not available for a Group item unfortunately, so what is the workaround? (if any)

Comment: I don't think that it is even conceptually possible to compare multiple items distances to a point without iterating through them.

If you look at the internal code that `Paper.js` uses for the [path.getNearestPoint()](http://paperjs.org/reference/path/#getnearestpoint-point) method you wished to use on a `Group`, you will see that it it what it does: it iterates through all the path curves and search the closest one to the point...

Do you have another algorithm idea than using a loop to do that ?

Comment: Other than iteration in that case, no. I had been looking at the `MouseEvent.target` property though as I thought it would give me more specificity as to what was targeted on the mouse event, but it returns the canvas, even when using the .stopPropagation() method

Answer (score 1):

This question can be resolved with the `.hitTest()` function which is also applicable to a `Group` object.

When using a mouse event such as 'click', within the callback function simply use the point from the event and feed it into the `<groupName>.hitTest()`.

Note that the options here can be quite crucial, make sure to specify the 'class' option as path (or another suitable paperJS `Item` derivative that you are looking for. In terms of additional options I resolved for the hit-test to only detect fill as all the items I am selecting are filled, if your items are not filled then set 'stroke' to true instead of 'fill' and  then make sure to click on the path boundary not the body of the shape. Below is an example of code to implement a mouse event followed by a hit-test:

```
tool.onMouseDown = function(event) {
    var result = groupItem.hitTest(event.point, {fill: true, stroke: false, segments: false, class: Path});
    console.log(result);
    result.item.selected = true;
```